# Browser is not caching images in HTTPS (HTTP works fine). Even with Cache-Control: public

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, http, ssl

I'm trying to follow [Google's caching recommendation](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching), but neither IE nor Chrome are caching my images when HTTPS is used. The second request is not even a conditional GET. If I simply switch to HTTP, it works fine.

Here's request information, according to Chrome's request logger:

```
Remote Address: ::1:443
Request URL: https://localhost/getmyimage.php?id=123
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept: image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=gbk4vk7ejlr20nqgajcqgskul7
Host: localhost
Referer: https://localhost/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
```

**Query String Parameters**

```
id: 123
```

**Response Headers**

```
Cache-Control: public
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 3224
Content-Type: image/png
Date: Tue, 27 May 2014 06:53:03 GMT
Expires: Mon, 25 Aug 2014 06:53:03 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Last-Modified: Mon, 24 Feb 2014 02:17:21 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.9
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9
```

Comment: Do you have any log of subsequent requests? Maybe they are "if modified since" and the problem is not in the browser, but in the server configuration... (Just guessing)

Comment: All requests are pretty much like that. There is no If-Modified-Since header.

Comment: Sometimes things are not as simple as they seems to be. May I have the server URL's that yields the problem?

Comment: It's already on my question. Look for Request URL.

Comment: :-( Sorry @fernacolo, I can't find a "live" URL in your request...(localhost?) I wanted to test subsequent request to the server to check if the issue is in your local client configuration or in the server handling of them.

Comment: I didn't deployed yet. Is there anything wrong about using localhost? Why wouldn't the browser cache?

Comment: Nothing wrong with localhost, just that I can't make any test.

Comment: Well. I've sent you ALL request headers and ALL response headers. I don't what could be different, since the browser itself is responsible for choosing what to put on request headers. All future requests (and responses) are identical. There is no cache happening. :-(

Comment: Noticed there was phpsession in the headers. Have you looked at `session_cache_limiter` as per this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1385982/1480215

Comment: @mfirdaus As you can see, the response (my code) is not sending any cookie. No session is being created or reused on the server for that request. It's the browser that sends that cookie because of other requests on same path.

Comment: In Windows, Chrome uses WinINet.  First thing I noticed is HTTPS, and there's an Internet Option for users to disallow caching secure content.  Then, you're providing a query string, I don't remember if WinINet always bypasses cache control headers.  Then, WinINet won't cache until it gets a full response, so if you have the same image in several places in your page, they will be fetched simultaneously for the first N images, where N is the amount of images that were downloaded in parallel until the first fully fetched one.  Your page may also have `meta` headers disabling cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this is happening because of the url format, you can use apache's mod_rewrite to make a url format for images given by this script to look like `localhost/image/123.png`

**EDIT**

after reading your comment, i can say that it's not about your server's config, you can't do anything about it according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687008/https-images-not-caching?answertab=active#tab-top) and [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7006/enable-browser-caching-with-https) because of HTTPS implementations since you have `Cache-control: public` set already.

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented it and didn't work. I found that if I use HTTP, it works. If I use HTTPS, it doesn't.

Comment: Browsers are ignoring Cache-control: public. *sigh*. I have to switch to [inline images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to avoid server trips.